# UI5 VizFrame Single Selection

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am currently building a Fiori app for viewing incidents (tickets). I had to create a pie chart with all the different states of the ticket. When I click on a part of the chart, It takes me to a list with all the tickets with that state. I can select more than one state of the pie chart, but I want only a single selection. https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/ui-components/selection/#!. I've found this and it says the default it multi-selection. Can anyone tell me how to change the chart's default value to single selection?

Any help is much appreciated
Matthijs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I accidentally stumbled on a solution. I'll post it in case someone needs to know.

```
interaction : {
          selectability : {
              mode : "single"
          }
 }
```